# Error al enviar correo con phpmailer, connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo instalado PHP v5.6.25 (utilizo la versión de 64x) y wampserver v3.0.6, Apache 2.4.23.

He realizado algunas modificaciones de puertos ya que he seguido varios tutoriales en youtube, pero no recuerdo puntualmente qué lineas he modificado.

Archivo php.ini www.dropbox.com/s/vnoxv38qqa67oez/php.ini?dl=0

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de envío de correos usando phpmailer, usando como host "smtp.gmail.com" he habilitado el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras de mi cuenta de gmail (myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Estuve siguiendo el siguiente tutorial: "Envío de correo por formulario con PHPMailer" (youtu.be/t4CZa-kHX5E) bajé los archivos que incluye en la descripción (PHPMailer) y (Código del programa) pero no he podido hacerlo funcionar.

Mi archivo PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$oMail = new PHPMailer();
$oMail->isSMTP();
$oMail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$oMail->Username = '********@gmail.com'; //Confidencial
$oMail->Password = '******************'; //Confidencial;

$oMail->SMTPAuth = true;
$oMail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$oMail->Port = 465; // 587 StartTLS - 465 ssl
$oMail->CharSet = "UTF-8";

/* Envio de mensaje */
$oMail->From = '*******@gmail.com'; //Remitente de GMAIL
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$oMail->addAddress($email); //Destinatario

$oMail->Subject = filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //asunto
$oMail->Body = filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //contenido

/***/
if($oMail->send() == false){
    echo "No se pudo enviar email";
    echo $oMail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
}?>
```

arroja el siguiente mensaje: 
[image]

Si al utilizar el servicio de host de Gmail 'smtp.gmail.com' con tipo de seguridad ssl, según esto www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/how-to-enable-imap-pop3-smtp-gmail-account.html  deberia utilizar el puerto 465... en este caso debo hacer alguna modificación en mi archivo php.ini?

Comment: Hola verifica, que tu servidor este soportando conexiones ssl, por el puerto 25. Sino puedes probar el envió de correo también con una cuenta de gmail.

Comment: Hola Fabian, tengo instalado wamp server v3.0.6 pero no se con seguridad si tengo habilitada la opción ssl. Con respecto al puerto, si, lo tengo configurado en el 25. (smtp_port =25). Me quedaría buscar como puedo habilitar ssl y te comento como me fue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿Cómo resolver este problema?**

La **mejor solución** sería contar con un certificado válido.

Pero cuando esto no es posible, se puede agregar lo siguiente a nuestro código:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
));
```

Otra posible solución que dan los creadores de PHP Mailer es crear nuestra propia clase personalizada, de la cual muestran un [ejemplo en este enlace](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Overriding-the-SMTP-class).

Answer (score 1):

el problema como dice Yoel es el puerto o la dirección que utilizas para autenticarte.

## mailtrap.io

Este es un servicio de pruebas, donde es como enviarte email a ti mismo,  puedes ocupar los puertos 25 o 465 o 2525

donde tu `usuario` y `contraseña` son los que te da el servicio, y son datos aleatorios. (nunca va a ser un email o contraseña que tu establezcas)

```
SMTP
Host:   smtp.mailtrap.io
Port:   25 or 465 or 2525
Username:   3482SoYuNaPruEb4
Password:   AASoYUnP4ssW0RDPruEb4
Auth:   PLAIN, LOGIN and CRAM-MD5
TLS:    Optional
```

Para este caso tu código quedaría así:

```
$oMail = new PHPMailer();

$oMail->isSMTP();
$oMail->Host = 'mailtrap.io';
$oMail->Username = '348264b5be11a85ac';  //IMPORTANTE
$oMail->Password = 'cc1b5b874803f7';  //IMPORTANTE

$oMail->SMTPAuth = true;
$oMail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$oMail->Port = 25;

$oMail->From = 'mail@sitioweb.com'; //Remitente
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$oMail->addAddress($email); //Destinatario

$oMail->Subject = filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //asunto
$oMail->Body = filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //contenido
```

### Gmail

Para el TLS de GMail es por el puerto 587 y debes haber habilitado la opción "permitir aplicaciones no seguras para envio de email" en tu configuración de seguridad.

> Gmail no es un servicio para mailing list y solo permite una cantidad
>   limitada de correos al día. El abuso del servicio puede provocar el bloqueo de la cuenta.

Por lo que los datos quedaría así:

```
$oMail = new PHPMailer();
$oMail->isSMTP();
$oMail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$oMail->Username = 'alguien@gmail.com';
$oMail->Password = 'abcd1234*';

$oMail->SMTPAuth = true;
$oMail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$oMail->Port = 587;  //IMPORTANTE

$oMail->From = 'alguien@gmail.com'; //Remitente de GMAIL
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$oMail->addAddress($email); //Destinatario

$oMail->Subject = filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //asunto
$oMail->Body = filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //contenido
```

Al final no importando la opción que elijas:

```
if($oMail->send() == false){
    echo "No se pudo enviar email";
    echo $oMail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
}
```

Comment: Esta información es útil pero no resuelve mi problema. Creo que debo verificar la habilitación de ssl de mi servidor wamp como me indico @Yoel Rodriguez

Comment: @MarcosGallardo gracias, pero olvidé comentar que ya había realizado esa instrucción. Voy a reeditar mi publicacion

Comment: al utilizar $oMail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; debo utilizar el puerto 587? en este caso debo hacer alguna modificación en mi archivo php.ini?

Comment: Has intentado hacerlo en otro que no sea WAMP ??  así descartamos algún error de configuración. Si hace lo mismo entonces ya se podría verificar.

Comment: voy a probar con xamp y te comento